# Shoulda-matcher How to validate uniqueness of enum attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I use rspec-rails with shoulda-matcher to test my model. Here is the code:

**user_ticket.rb**

```
class UserTicket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ticket

  enum relation_type: %w( creator supporter )

  validates_uniqueness_of :relation_type, scope: [:user_id, :ticket_id]
end
```

**user_ticket_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe UserTicket, type: :model do
  subject { FactoryGirl.build(:user_ticket) }

  describe 'Relations' do
    it { should belong_to(:user) }
    it { should belong_to(:ticket) }
  end

  describe 'Validations' do
    it { should define_enum_for(:relation_type).with(%w( creator supporter )) }
    # PROBLEM HERE
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:relation_type).case_insensitive.scoped_to([:user_id, :ticket_id]) }
  end
end
```

When I run the test case the result is always:

```
Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:relation_type).case_insensitive.scoped_to([:user_id, :ticket_id]) }

     ArgumentError:
       'CREATOR' is not a valid relation_type
```

I just think shoulda matcher wants to validate the uniqueness with some kinds of `relation_type` values: uppercase, lowercase,..etc. My question is in this situation, how to make the test pass with such of defined model validations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's failing because you're asking it to test *validation* case insensitively. Typically this would be used to test a range of values with different cases cause validation to fail. However, you're not even allowed to set the value because of the enum; it doesn't even get to the validation check.

It is testing the validation with "creator" and "CREATOR" (at least). `enum`s are case sensitive so these would be two different values in the `enum` and you've only declared "creator". When it tries to assign "CREATOR" to test the validation your `enum` gets upset and refuses to allow it.

You may want to validate the uniqueness without case sensitivity in which case you want:

```
validate_uniqueness_of(:relation_type).ignoring_case_sensitivity
```

From the [validates_uniqueness_of](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/Shoulda%2FMatchers%2FActiveRecord%3Avalidate_uniqueness_of) docs:

> By default, validate_uniqueness_of will check that the validation is case sensitive: it asserts that uniquable attributes pass validation when their values are in a different case than corresponding attributes in the pre-existing record.
>
> Use ignoring_case_sensitivity to skip this check.

Or you might want to skip the uniqueness checks in your test altogether and trust that rails only allows unique values in an `enum`.

Comment: about: "skip the uniqueness checks", what if we need to use scope, 
`validates_uniqueness_of :type, scope: :user_id`, unfortunately this check is not working in this case: `it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:type).scoped_to(:user_id) }`. So need to extend `shoulda` or write the test manually

Comment: Seems legit https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/997